# Difference between Docker for AWS and Docker Cloud?

Tags: docker

I am trying to understand what is the difference between  Docker for AWS and Docker Cloud linked to AWS? Could someone explain this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming, but a docker admin question, and also, should probably be directed at amazon, not us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker Cloud is basically an hosted solution by Docker.

Docker for AWS is actually the Docker Enterprise Edition that will be hosted on your AWS account. It's not Docker Cloud for AWS, it's Docker EE for AWS.

Docker Cloud and Docker EE are not the same thing.